# How to stop at first match using regex_iterator of cpp

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am using cpp regex library to find a regular expression match in the text. I have written my own iterators (to skip certain characters in the text) that i pass to regex_iterator. My problem is that it returns the results which contain all the matches found in the text. I don't want regex_iterator to continue searching the text even after the first match is found since the first match is all I need.

Also if this is not possible in cpp regex, is it possible in boost?

Sample code:

```
    regex_iterator<MyIterator> rit ( cdogs, cdogs.end(), e );
    regex_iterator<MyIterator> rend;

    while (rit!=rend) {
        cout << rit->str() << std::endl;
        ++rit;
    }
```

Comment: If you only want the first match, why use iterators at all?

Comment: I am using iterators because my text contains few control characters which i want to skip during search. For this i have written a filter iterators and am passing this iterator to the regex_iterator.

Comment: In that case what is preventing the use of regex_search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to find the second match, don't increment `rit` and simply return instead.

```
template<typename Dogs, typename E>
std::pair<bool, std::string> find_it( Dogs&& cdogs, E&& e ) {
  std::regex_iterator<MyIterator> rit ( cdogs, cdogs.end(), e );

  if (rit!=std::regex_iterator<MyIterator>()) {
    return std::make_pair( true, rit->str() );
  }
  return std::make_pair( false, std::string() );
}
```

which is a function that returns a pair, the first of which is "did I find anything", the second is the string that was found (if the first was true).  You can instead use `boost::optional<std::string>`, which expresses this better, as a return value.

Comment: I think what i wrote was ambiguous, will edit it. What I meant was that rit gets populated with all the matches when regex_iterator is called. Since I'll be dealing with huge text, and only 1st match would be required, I want regex_iterator to return as soon as first match is found.

Comment: Yakk, what you answered is not the answer to my question, I have edited the question to make it more clear. Can you please go through that again and answer accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: @user976111 What evidence do you have that `regex_iterator` reads beyond the current match?  [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) for `regex_iterator` implies that it doesn't do this...

Comment: I wonder if it is sensible to recommend to not use iterators at all.

Comment: @phresnel You mean, just call `std::regex_search` using `MyIterator`s?  So crazy it just might work.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes. It somehow sounds wasteful to me to have iterators over match-results, when you really just want the first match. Maybe I am missing something, though.

Comment: @user976111 - `regex_iterator` does **not** get populated with all the matches. Its constructor searches up to the first match, and each time you increment it, it searches for the next match.

Comment: OK, my bad. I was missing this. As written by @PeteBecker regex_iterator does not get populates result with all the matches. Thanks Yakk.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks like it already does what you want [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator). Not specifically this line

`On construction, and on every increment, it calls std::regex_search and remembers the result`

So it only calculates when you increment your pointer. With that said, you can simply do:

```
regex_iterator<MyIterator> rit ( cdogs, cdogs.end(), e );
regex_iterator<MyIterator> rend;
return rit != rend ? rit->str() :  "";
```